# How to transpose a data frame in R in a way that the elements of a character variable become columns in the new data frame

Tags: r

Here's an example of a data frame I am using.

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,3)
Type <- c('A', 'B', 'A', 'A')
Value <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
df <- data.frame(ID,Type,Value)
df
```

And here's how df looks like:

| ID | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2.5 |
| 1 | B | 8.0 |
| 2 | A | 10.0 |
| 3 | A | 7.0 |

I'm looking for a way to transpose df in a way that the elements of the character variable "Type" become columns in the new data frame.

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 | 8 |
| 2 | 10.0 | 0 |
| 3 | 7.0 | 0 |

Note that for IDs 2 and 3, where only type A values are present in df, I'd like to have zero values under column B in the new data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Value, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     ID     A     B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.5     8
2     2  10       0
3     3   7       0
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID, Type, Value)
```